# AWS SSM - store multiple parameters using terraform and json file

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

We have a couple of legacy applications we're migrating to ec2 and these use a bunch of application configuration parameters. I need to be able to store each config as an individual parameter per application.

I'm trying the following but clearly not doing it right as it appends all values to a single parameter per application:

```
locals {
  application = {
    "application1" = { app_shortcode = "app1"},
    "application2" = { app_shortcode = "app2"}
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "application_parameters" {
  for_each = local.application
  name     = each.key
  value    = jsonencode(file("${path.module}/${each.key}/ssm_param.json"))
}
```

my `app1`'s `ssm_param.json` is something like

```
{
    "app1_config1": "config_value_1",
    "app1_config2": "config_value_2",
    "app1_config3": "config_value_3"
}
```

and `app2`'s `ssm_param.json`is

```
{
    "app2_config_a": "config_value_a",
    "app2_config_b": "config_value_b",
    "app2_config_c": "config_value_c"
}
```

The current output is a single parameter like this for each application:
`"{\r\n    \"app2_config_a\": \"config_value_a\",\r\n    \"app2_config_b\": \"config_value_b\"\r\n, \r\n    \"app2_config_c\": \"config_value_c\"\r\n}"`

Looking for suggestions please.

Comment: What is `local.application`?

Comment: edited my question to include locals

Comment: Are you sure this is your real, actual code? I don't see how it could produce only a single ssm paramter.

Comment: other than changing config values, yes. actual code. I'd like to correct myself, terraform creates a single parameter per application

Comment: In locals, I think you don't need a comma after app1. But I don't know if this is the root issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using a slightly different approach (not quite the same as my initial one but this works for me for now):

used a `ssm_params.yaml` as below (the project team was kind enough to give me the config settings as yaml output)

```
parameter:
    app1:
      name: app1_config1
      description: "application config test"
      type: "String"
      value: "some_randoM_value"
    app1:
      name: app_config2
      description: "another test"
      type: "SecureString"
      value: "some_random123_value###"
    app2:
      name: app_config_2
      description: "config test"
      type: "String"
      value: "some_randoM_value_2"
```

> ```
> locals {
> params             = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/ssm_params.yaml"))
> }
>
> resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "app_params" {
>   for_each = local.params.parameter
>   name     = each.value.name
>   type     = each.value.type
>   value    = each.value.value
> }
> ```

Comment: Nice approach, but I prefer to use each app params in an isolated yml file.

Comment: I'd prefer the same but i'm unsure if the project team would be kind enough to do that for me :)